# How to put local dependencies first when calling gradle idea?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, jar, classpath

When calling `gradle idea`, external dependencies are ordered first in the class path relatively to local Jar inclusions. As such :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include:['*.jar'])
    compile group: 'foo', name:'bar', version:'1.0.0'
}
```

will include my local jars last. This is a problem in my project as these jars' purpose is to partially overwrite the external library.

The same behavior is observed when specifying the repository as a source of dependencies using `flatDir` and loading the jar without `fileTree`. It is put last in the classpath.

I have found several mentions of the problem when researching, such as https://discuss.gradle.org/t/gradle-messes-up-the-classpath-order-in-generated-projects-when-there-are-mixed-dependency-types/13130, but no workarounds.

I suppose these exist, gradle being very customisable, but being very new to it my attempts to make one fail.  How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not using IntelliJ on a regular basis but tried it in the context of this question and my impression is that gradle's `idea` plugin and IntelliJ's gradle plugin don't go well together. That is you should either use the `idea` gradle plugin and import as plain Java project or import as gradle project using IntelliJ's gradle plugin. Main reason is that the `idea` plugin and the IntelliJ plugin are generating slightly different iml-files (those files are holding the project dependencies - amongst others) which leads to lot of confusion when using both plugins together. As you specifically asked for the gradle `idea` plugin, I used this plugin and imported into IntelliJ as plain java project.

But to answer your question I found no evidence that the order of libraries on the classpath differs from the order as declared in the `dependencies` section of the gradle file, when using a `flatDir` repo. When using `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include:['*.jar'])` the order was actually broken as described in your question. That is, you should stick to using a `flatDir` repo.

I'm using gradle 4.9 and IntelliJ 2018.2.

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'zzz:zzz-0.0.0'
    compile 'aaa:aaa-0.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre'
    compile group: 'javax.websocket', name: 'javax.websocket-api', version: '1.1'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.9'
    distributionUrl = "http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-${gradleVersion}-bin.zip"
}
```

In my `libs` folder there are two jars `aaa-0.0.0.jar` and `zzz-0.0.0.jar` both are copies of `guava-24.0-jre.jar`. That is all guava classes are present in both jars as well. As `zzz:zzz-0.0.0` is the first dependency in the gradle file, the expectation would be that guava classes are being loaded from `zzz-0.0.0.jar` instead of `guava-24.0-jre.jar` or `aaa-0.0.0.jar`. I used the following main class to test this:

```
package test;

import com.google.common.math.LongMath;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws  Exception {
        System.out.println(LongMath.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI());
    }
}
```

And the output when running it from IntelliJ is

file:/C:/ws/gradle-idea-test/libs/zzz-0.0.0.jar

That is the `com.google.common.math.LongMath` class is indeed being loaded from the local `libs/zzz-0.0.0.jar` instead of the `guava-24.0-jre.jar`.

I noticed that the list of external dependencies in IntelliJ doesn't show the local libraries. And even more confusing the libraries are ordered alphabetically and don't reflect the actual order on the classpath which might be quite confusing:

[image: IntelliJ External Dependencies]

To get the actual order of elements on the classpath you will have to look in the module dependencies section in the module settings ("Open Module Settings" > "Project" > "Modules" > "Dependencies Tab") which looks like this:

[image: IntelliJ Module Dependencies]

As you can see the dependencies are listed in correct order and include the local libraries as well. The order of libs in this dialog is basically the same as in the generated iml-file.

When using the IntelliJ gradle plugin instead of gradle's `idea` plugin, IntelliJ basically behaved the same way but the generated iml-file looked different and the external libraries were displayed in a different format. But there was no difference regarding the classpath order.